# How can I compare 2 lists in different excel files and highlight the changes?

Tags: excel, vba

Let 18jan.xlsx contain the following data:

```
ABC 10
XYZ 20
PQR 30
STU 40
DEF 50
HIJ 60
KLM 70
```

19jan.xlsx contain:

```
XYZ 20
ABC 15
STU 40
DEF 50
HIJ 65
PQR 30
KLM 70
```

I need to compare them and highlight the changes, for example here 15 in front of ABC should be highlighted. And also I need to do this daily with dates changed.

Comment: The problem I am facing is running the two loops, one to compare the first column and then comparing the corresponding number

Comment: @AjinkyaBadhan can you show us what your expected results based on the above sample? `=)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is placed in columns `A:B` starting row 1, the following code should do the job:

```
Sub DailyDataHighlight()

Dim InputFolder As String
Dim OldExcel As String
Dim NewExcel As String

Dim i As Long
Dim OldString As String
Dim OldValue As String
Dim NewValue As String
Dim SearchResult As Range

InputFolder = "D:\DOCUMENTS\"
OldExcel = "18jan.xlsx"
NewExcel = "19jan.xlsx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Workbooks.Open (InputFolder & OldExcel)
Application.Workbooks.Open (InputFolder & NewExcel)

For i = 1 To Workbooks(OldExcel).ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    OldString = Workbooks(OldExcel).ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text
    OldValue = Workbooks(OldExcel).ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Text
    Set SearchResult = Workbooks(NewExcel).ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set SearchResult = SearchResult.Find(OldString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
        NewValue = SearchResult.Offset(0, 1).Text
        If NewValue <> OldValue Then SearchResult.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

Next i

Workbooks(NewExcel).Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Assumptions and details:

1. Data range is practically unlimited.
2. Both files are placed in the same folder. Names & Path should be defined in code.
3. "Highlight" is done using cell fill, change `.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)` as required.
4. Only first and only occurrence of key string is checked for change (based on the input).

Sample file is shared as well: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqkulovmg98yaih/DailyDataHighlight.xlsm

Hope that was helpful in learning VBA either)